# How use specific commands

Tags: apt, kernel, vmware, linux-headers

I'm trying to install VMware. But because of some difficulties, I followed [a tutorial which lists some commands](https://develmonk.com/2020/06/06/whats-wrong-with-vmware-workstation-on-ubuntu/) to resolve my problems. I see this commands:

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r) linux-modules-$(uname -r)
```

but I don't know how to use it. Should I replace `uname -r` by my username? I tried many ways but nothing works well.

Comment: No you don’t replace uname. It’s a Linux command that returns the kernel version

Comment: but my terminal respons $: command not found

Comment: Check that the command you have entered is exactly the same as the tutorial you are following. You can also check that uname -r works correctly by just typing that into the terminal

Comment: when i type uname -r i get a result. But when i type all the commande i get $ : command not found.... i type excately the command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should enter the terminal without first dollar sign.

<strike>First dollar sign ($) tells to you, this is a terminal command.</strike> 

First dollar sign ( $ ) means you are a normal user.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r) linux-modules-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: Ok it work well, thanks very much

Comment: Good spot! +1 for that